# How to compile a python program?

Tags: python, compiler-construction

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Compiling Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434144/compiling-python)

I would like to know if it is possibl to write a program in Python and compile it into an executable?

I mean actual compiling, not interpreting.

The main reason is this would be a commercial product so the need to "hide" the source code is there.

So basically I'd like to take a .py file and turn it into a .exe file.

Any suggestions?

Comment: [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/)

Answer (score 0):

You can distribute compiled .pyc files instead of .py source code files. .pyc are generated on the fly when Python program is run. .pyc files are bytecode (think Java .class files) and resist attempts to reverse engineer them.

Comment: They do not resist attempts to reverse-engineer them very hard.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/).

Comment: I'd like it to be cross-platform

Comment: You should write this in your question. Now I see the question about exe files only. Anyway, I can't help you in this case.